# Can I create a Visual Studio 2019 project from existing C code?

Tags: visual-studio, embedded

Here is my current setup:
Some C code (some embedded code) in a folder and subfolders. Organised as I needed and how the embedded editor needed.

If I use Eclipse to create a new C project and place the project file in the root of my sourcecode, then Eclipse will find all folders and files, then index them correctly. I then able to browse the files as a project, functions linked to other files, defines are showing up correctly.

Now, our version control is Visual Studio 2019, and I'm looking for a solution or guide, how to open the same file structure in visual Studio instead of Eclipse. I don't want to open the Eclipse project, I try to drop the use of Eclipse, so I can just use one tool to version control the files and browse the code for editing. I also don't want to compile, debug in visual Studio, I can use the dedicated environment for that. I only want to edit the files like it would be in Eclipse, save the files as the VS editor is much better than the embedded editor. (By the way, the embedded studio IAR and it's editor is horrible, hence why I used Eclipse in the past, but I don't want to open IAR project in VS, just a nice editor needed from VS.)

Any suggestions? Anyone done this successfully?

Comment: I seriously don't think you'll ever find a worse IDE than Eclipse. Personally I never had any problems with IAR, but if you do embedded and don't like IAR, then maybe check out [Crossworks](https://www.rowley.co.uk)? Because working with multiple projects in multiple IDEs kind of sucks... been there too, each time I had to get rid of a broken Eclipse fiasco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open VS2019 directly (i.e. not via a source or project file) you should be presented with a start page that includes this:

[image]

Select "Open a local folder" and it will present the project from the root you select.  It will even apply IntelliSense for code completion for symbols within the selected code base.  For headers external to the project tree, you can add include search paths to get better navigation, browsing and completion.

A more comprehensive integration with IAR is possible using VisualGDB extension as described [here](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/import/iar/).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. Simple enough to keep me working in a well balanced text editor.